# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'auto_increment'

Tags: sql-server, azure, spring-boot

When I try to build a table in Azure, it says "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'auto_increment'."
However, when I build in my local database, it's fine.
Can anyone help me with this? Thank you so much.
And I don't know where to fix the auto_increment rule, I didn't write it.

**This is local driver I used before**

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

**This is my MS JDBC driver**

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

**This is my table class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "notes")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"createdAt", "updatedAt"},
        allowGetters = true)
public class Note implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    private String title;

    @NotBlank
    private String content;

    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdAt;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date updatedAt;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public Date getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(Date updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a mismatch in drivers.  'auto_increment' is MySQL syntax, and will not work with the SQL Server driver you are using.

Answer (score 0):

spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect

After I used this driver, it works. Thank you Greg!